# Dataframe grouping

Tags: python, pandas

```
data=

                              open     high      low    close  volume
timestamp                                                            
2015-02-02 09:15:00+05:30  1280.00  1286.00  1280.00  1284.55    5847
2015-02-02 09:16:00+05:30  1284.55  1290.00  1283.90  1284.05     260
2015-02-02 09:17:00+05:30  1284.05  1288.20  1280.30  1283.90     424
2015-02-02 09:18:00+05:30  1283.90  1285.75  1283.90  1285.35      40
2015-02-02 09:19:00+05:30  1285.35  1290.00  1283.30  1285.40     203
2015-02-02 09:20:00+05:30  1285.35  1286.00  1283.50  1284.65     267
```

Want to get/group `2H` data starting from 9:00:00.

For `1H` data I tried:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1h')).agg({"open":"first","close":"last","low":"min","high":"max","volume":"sum"})
```

It appears result as follows:

```
                              open    close      low     high  volume
timestamp                                                            
2015-02-02 09:00:00+05:30  1280.00  1285.65  1280.00  1290.00   12620
2015-02-02 10:00:00+05:30  1285.65  1281.00  1281.00  1294.00    5103
2015-02-02 11:00:00+05:30  1281.00  1261.55  1261.20  1284.40    8995
2015-02-02 12:00:00+05:30  1261.30  1266.00  1256.00  1267.00   12772
2015-02-02 13:00:00+05:30  1266.00  1263.85  1260.00  1266.85    4076
2015-02-02 14:00:00+05:30  1261.35  1264.60  1260.00  1268.00    5937
2015-02-02 15:00:00+05:30  1263.00  1262.00  1256.65  1265.00    9505
2015-02-02 16:00:00+05:30      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       0
2015-02-02 17:00:00+05:30      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       0
```

How to remove `NaN` lines?

For `2H`, in place of `1H`, result:

```
                              open    close      low    high  volume
timestamp                                                           
2015-02-02 08:00:00+05:30  1280.00  1285.65  1280.00  1290.0   12620
2015-02-02 10:00:00+05:30  1285.65  1261.55  1261.20  1294.0   14098
2015-02-02 12:00:00+05:30  1261.30  1263.85  1256.00  1267.0   16848
2015-02-02 14:00:00+05:30  1261.35  1262.00  1256.65  1268.0   15442
2015-02-02 16:00:00+05:30      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN       0
2015-02-02 18:00:00+05:30      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN       0
```

Two problems: 1. `NaN` rows for outside trading hour. 2. Want it to start from 9AM.

This I think will work, but not sure:

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2h', offset='1h')).agg({"open":"first","close":"last","low":"min","high":"max","volume":"sum"})
```

If I try for a `7min` or `7H` timeframe (just to generalize) offset will not work properly, as `60min` is not divisible by 7... It will work for `2min`, `3min`, `4min`, `5min`, `6min`, etc... Any help, on how to generalize?

Comment: Did you consider using `dropna` to remove the rows with `NaNs`? Regarding your second question using `offset='1h'` works for me.

Comment: @gofvonx, yes that works. But, if I try for a 7min or 7hr timeframe (just to generalize) `offset` will not work properly, as 60min is not divisible by 7... It will work for 2min, 3min, 4min, 5min, 6min, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Grouper and resample output are the same, but if you add `origin="2015-02-09 09:00:00"`, the output will be from the specified date and time.
I am getting my Apple data from Yahoo Finance. I am removing the time zone for the data I get. The start time was 9:30, so `origin=` is set to 9:30.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download("AAPL", interval='1m', start="2021-03-01", end="2021-03-08")
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)

df_2h_origin = df.resample('2h', origin='2021-03-01 09:30:00').agg({"Open":"first","Close":"last","Low":"min","High":"max","Volume":"sum"})
df_2h_origin.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace=True)

df_2h_origin.head()

    Open    Close   Low     High    Volume
Datetime                    
2021-03-01 09:30:00     123.500000  125.879898  122.790001  126.154999  46633988
2021-03-01 11:30:00     125.879997  126.209297  125.669998  126.620003  21994558
2021-03-01 13:30:00     126.205002  127.559998  126.089996  127.750000  24004585
2021-03-01 15:30:00     127.565002  127.790001  127.269997  127.930000  11684669
2021-03-02 09:30:00     128.410004  125.959999  125.500000  128.720001  41931239
```